# What Control unit has the power in a multicore cpu?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, cpu-architecture

A processor with cores is just a bunch of single cpus thrown together on a single IC (Integrated circuit)(That's why my /proc/cpuinfo shows 4 of them).
A CPU is made up of some sub-units always including (according to von neumans computers) an ALU and a Control unit.

[I watched this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNN_tTXABUA)

> In a way, the CU is the "brain within the brain": [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit#Functions_of_the_control_unit)

It handles the cpu data Bus, the memory registers and the I/O, with enable and set wires.

How does this work with multiple of them? Is like one of them chosen to be the cu of cus?

(I know this is a silly question sorry for that.. I just need to know it.. seriously)

Comment: The answer is multiple threads at the software level.

Comment: *"A processor with cores ..."* -- No, a processor would have only one core, aka the CPU.  A *multi*processor has several cores.  *"Is like one of them chosen to be the cu of cus?"* -- The multiprocessor (or multicore) systems you are likely to encounter are probably all symmetric multiprocessor (SMP) architecture.  Each processor is identical to any other in capability, hence the symmetry.  Only one designated processor in a SMP system does have the responsibility of handling a reset/startup. So no, there is no CPU in a SMP computer.

Comment: Thanks! that helped. I am kind a new to the stackexchange network.
is there a reason you commented this, instead of posting it as an answer?

Comment: Usually to help you clear up a misunderstanding, and give you a chance to clarify your question. Some may also not have the reputation to post an answer (but he has 10k, so no issue)